# When should [download] be used?

Tags: discussion, tags

I wanted to ask when the tag [download](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/download) should be used?

To me it seems to be a rather useless tag since in the 150 question nearly half seem to be about `wget` and the other half about `curl`.

And some are about downloading distros.

So what is the purpose of [download](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/download)?

Comment: Hmm. Good question. I don't really see much use for it at all. Let's see what the community thinks.

Comment: I agree, it seems like a useless tag and should probably be removed.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see a need for it; who is out there looking for questions to answer about "downloads"? I think there would be a piece of software involved (wget, curl, etc) that could be tagged, instead.

Answer (score 0):

#### Rationale

I can only see two valid question types with that tag:

- Connectivity problems with tools that perform downloads.  Example: [question about RHEL packages without connectivity](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261465/problem-in-installing-new-software-rhel6).  Should probably be tagged with the piece of software used ([rpm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpm) in the example question).
- Question concerning operation on files that are still incomplete due to the fact that they're being operated on.  This is a little harder, I believe:

  - This [question about monitoring the downloads directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281139/check-in-pure-bash-that-the-download-is-complete) would be as valid if, instead of firefox, curl or wget was used (let's imagine that it is some wget process running in the background).
  - And [this question about uploading a file that is being generated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248762/can-i-download-tar-gz-file-while-it-is-being-compressed) is also independent of the program used for the upload/download.  Moreover OP is asking what program he can use to perform the upload/download.

Notably, the last example question (just above) would be poorer without the [download](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/download). On the other hand it is arguable that *download* is a poor definition for what OP is looking for.  He is actually looking for a [file-transfer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-transfer).  The same can be said about the question on download monitoring.

#### Conclusion

In my humble opinion [download](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/download) should be synonymized to [file-transfer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-transfer).

Answer (score 0):

[Playing Devil's Advocate to Jeff Schaller's answer for voting purposes; I haven't actually looked up the tag itself]

I see a need for it; I often see someone asking a question to help them use a command-line tool to "download" something [usually scraping; occasionally something more interesting]. There may be a piece of software involved (wget, curl, etc.) that is mistakenly tagged, instead, but the questioner [doesn't actually care about the minutiae of that software](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) but just wants to learn how to *download* something.

Comment: Then use the tag for *that* tool instead, we don't need a question tagged [apt] [download] when you want to use apt to download packages, just apt will do. BTW, it's very likely that ends up downvoted because the answer is in the man page/builtin help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the download tag is meant for downloads that aren't wget, curl, and the like.
However, it's being mis-used, and so wget and curl questions have the tag on them.
My solution, is if there are already wget and curl tags, move those questions to them.
Alternatively, we could just delete download altogether.

Answer (score -1):

What if someone wants to generally look for a [download](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/download), and not just [wget](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wget) or [curl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curl)?
Then, [download](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/download) seems useful. <sup>No, [wget](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wget)[curl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curl) is not a correct search term, what if a new tool gets added?</sup>

Comment: Do you mean questions like "Where can I download X?" or what do you mean by "generally look for a download".

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens The [tag:download] tag is surely needed, if a new download tool tag gets added, then you won't get coverage for that tool if you search for `[wget][curl]`, but you *will* if you search for `[download]`.

Comment: If you mean questions of the type "where can I download something?" then I'm not sure it's a good fit for the site.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I don't think SE has such feature, but no, I mean something like "Download problem!" (for a tool no tag exists) or "New tool, but I don't have enough rep!" (for mods; create the tag, then delete the post). But, anyways, the [tag:download] tag *is* needed, not everyone will hassle because they need to search for "[wget][curl][tool1][tool2][tool3][tool-et-cetera][tool-...][...]"